# C# execute multiple commands in textbox [mysql c#]

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio, connection

Well like the title says i need to execute multiple commands that are in a textbox. 
For example: 
http://i.imgur.com/AKPNSKU.png "tooltip"

execute commands individually one by one it is easy,but to execute multiple commands and That my textbox  separate one by one the commands..how can I do this ?. Hope you can give me some ideas. (I was thinking of using multiple textbox, each have a command,but i dont know how it will work.)

Comment: You will have to find some way of differentiating where one command starts and the next begins

Comment: Please don't use a picture for text. It's cumbersome and far less usable.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Comment: I just said you don't vandalize. I repeat. Don't vandalize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your image, you could split the commands on the semi-colon (into an array of commands) and iterate over them, executing one at a time.  I assume you would want some exception handling to abort if you hit an error along the way...possibly even wrap the whole thing in a transaction so you don't half cook things.

**UPDATE**: Some C# code to split the commands on the semi-colon - assumes your text box is named textBox1.

```
foreach (string command in textBox1.Text.Split(';'))
{
    // execute command
}
```

**NOTES**: You still haven't shown how you are executing the single command, so I'll just leave it at the comment to execute.  However, I would consider the following to make your code more maintainable and fault-tolerant:

1. Don't just interact with the DB directly from the UI - You should have some sort of data access layer that accepts the commands for execution.
2. You should have exception handling so you are able to deal with invalid commands and provide meaningful feedback about errors.
3. Related to #2, if you have an error in one of the commands, what should you do?  I would think that you should execute them all as a transaction, so in the case of an exception, you can rollback previous commands and recover.

Comment: You haven't even indicated the language you are using.  You said it was easy to execute a single command - how are you doing this?